# Manually initializing a cv::Matx?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some camera calibration data, in this format:

```
  0.3072423    -0.0104122    -0.9515744     -208.5614
0.003617216     0.9999457  -0.009773563     -4.705516
  0.9516244 -0.0004391983     0.3072633     -152.5427
          0             0             0             1
```

I have a function that takes `const cv::Matx<T, 4, 4>& M` as an argument. (From third party code)

```
template<typename T>
cv::Matx<T, 6, 1> hom2cayley(const cv::Matx<T, 4, 4>& M)
{
    cv::Matx<T, 3, 3> R(M(0, 0), M(0, 1), M(0, 2),
        M(1, 0), M(1, 1), M(1, 2),
        M(2, 0), M(2, 1), M(2, 2));
    cv::Matx<T, 3, 1> C = rot2cayley(R);

    return cv::Matx<T, 6, 1>(C(0, 0), C(1, 0), C(2, 0),
        M(0, 3), M(1, 3), M(2, 3));
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do i manually fill a `Matx` with the values above, so that i can pass it to the function?

I have:

```
void main()
{
    template<typename T>

    const cv::Matx<T, 4, 4> camData{ 0.3072423, - 0.0104122, - 0.9515744, - 208.5614,
        0.003617216,     0.9999457, - 0.009773563, - 4.705516,
        0.9516244, - 0.0004391983,     0.3072633, - 152.5427,
        0 ,            0 ,            0    ,         1 };

    hom2cayley(camData);  //invalid argument, camData is undefined.
}
```

...but it gives the errors above. What are my mistakes here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main you have to use Matx of specific type. For your purpose it is float or double. Replace `cv::Matx<T, 4, 4>` with `cv::Matx<double, 4, 4>` and delete `template<typename T>` in main.